# What is the translation of דורמיטא? (Dormita)

Tags: torah-study, grammar-dikduk, mysticism-kabbalah

What is the translation of דורמיטא? (Dormita)

Is this something from the realms of kabbalah?

When I searched Sefaria [here](https://www.sefaria.org/search?q=%D7%94%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%98%D7%90&tab=text&tvar=1&tsort=relevance&svar=1&ssort=relevance), I found it mentioned many times in the context of Kabbalah, but I still don't understand the meaning of it.

Comment: דורמיטא is kabbalistic and explained as a "state of slumber" of G-d.

Comment: can you please put that in answer form

Comment: See: Zohar, Idra Rabba 46:324, [Time to Wake Up by GalEinai](https://www.inner.org/hebrew_calendar/tishrei/time-to-wake-up#_ftn1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not that familiair with this kabbalistic concept, but basically what it means is that דורמיטא means that G-d is in a "state of slumber". This can be deduced from what it writes in Tehillim 44:24:

> Awake, why sleepest Thou, O L-rd? arise, cast us not off for ever.

See the commentary of the [Zohar Idra Rabba 46:324 (ad loc.)](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.44.24?lang=bi&p2=Zohar%2C_Idra_Rabba.46.324&lang2=bi).

The concept is explained [here](https://hitbonenut.net/archives/6546):

> הדורמיטא היא מצב דומה. סוג של שינה. בערב ראש השנה העולם נכנס לתרדמת. כלומר העולם ממשיך להתקיים. הדברים מתנהלים. מכוניות נוסעות. בני האדם הולכים, מדברים, אוכלים, שותים. אבל הדברים מתרחשים כמו באוטומט, בדומה להתנהלות הגוף ללא הכוונה בקטעי הנהיגה המדוברים. Dormita is a similair state of being in a coma. On the eve of Rosh Hashanah, the world goes into a coma (so to speak). That is, the world continues to exist. Things are going on. Cars are driving. Humans walk, talk, eat, drink. But things happen as if in an automatic

The article asks why is this necessary/happening?

> מדוע זה קורה? השינה של העולם מתקיימת כדי שיתאפשר רענון לעולם. בשפת הקבלה מדובר בתהליך של הסתלקות השנה שעברה, עליית העולמות למקורן וגילוי של שנה חדשה, פעימת חיות שלא הייתה קיימת קודם לכן. The sleep of the world takes place so that the world can be refreshed. In the language of Kabbalah, it is a process of leaving the last year [...]

> On Rosh Hashanah, a new spiritual and physical abundance is drawn from the upper worlds, which is used throughout the year. Therefore Rosh Hashanah is like the beginning of all the days of the year.